# Telescope and SDL Tridion Integration

Tags: 2013-sp1-hr1

Is there an existing ECL developed to connect the [Telescope DAM](http://www.northplains.com/telescope/) and SDL Tridion? I've heard there was, but I am not able to find any details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is an ECL connector for Telescope, owned and built by NorthPlains themselves.

I can't find much info online about this connector - you should probably reach out to NorthPlains directly.

Answer (score 3):

yes there is an ECL connector for Northplains Telescope. It is developed by [Tahzoo (formerly Hinttech)](http://www.tahzoo.com/)

It works with Tridion 2013 and provides nice features including search, metadata, direct links to Telescope assets, and Where Used. I would reach out to Tahzoo for more details as it is usually provided with an implementation package.

Comment: So not a public community project? Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, not public